# How to add two inputs and save them as lists of lists continuously?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-requests

For instance you have to take two values one is name of item and other is price of item. And you want to store that information in same list as a list of list.
Say if the price of banana is 10, apple is 20 and orange is 30 then the list should look like this:

```
[(banana , 10) , (apple , 20) (orange , 30) ].
```

Please not that we will asks user to input both of these values.

Comment: Please provide the code that you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by creating empty list and then append user input to this list.
using while loop user can provide more than one fruit and its price.
By defining exit value 'quit' you can tell program when to stop while loop.

```
lst = []
while True:
    fruit = input('Enter Fruit or if you want to quit type ''quit'' : ')
    if fruit == 'quit':
        break
    price = int(input('Enter price : '))
    lst.append([fruit, price])

print(lst)
```